# Can nvidia-docker be run without a GPU?

Tags: docker, cuda, pytorch, nvidia-docker

The official PyTorch [Docker image](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/docker/pytorch/Dockerfile) is based on [`nvidia/cuda`](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/), which is able to run on Docker CE, without any GPU. It can also run on [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker), I presume with CUDA support enabled. Is it possible to run nvidia-docker itself on an x86 CPU, without any GPU? Is there a way to build a single Docker image that takes advantage of CUDA support when it is available (e.g. when running inside `nvidia-docker`) and uses the CPU otherwise? What happens when you use `torch.cuda` from inside Docker CE? What exactly is the difference between Docker CE and why can't `nvidia-docker` be merged into Docker CE?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`nvidia-docker` is a shortcut for `docker --runtime nvidia`. I do hope they merge it one day, but for now it's a 3rd party runtime. They explain what it is and what it does on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-runtime).

> A modified version of runc adding a custom pre-start hook to all containers.
>   If environment variable NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is set in the OCI spec, the hook will configure GPU access for the container by leveraging nvidia-container-cli from project libnvidia-container.

Nothing stops you from running images meant for `nvidia-docker` with normal `docker`. They work just fine but if you run something in them that requires the GPU, that will fail.

I don't think you can run `nvidia-docker` on a machine without a GPU. It won't be able to find the CUDA files it's looking for and will error out.

To create an image that can run on both `docker` and `nvidia-docker`, your program inside it needs to be able to know where it's running. I am not sure if there's an official way, but you can try one of the following:

- Check if `nvidia-smi` is available
- Check if the directory specified in `$CUDA_LIB_PATH` exists
- Check if your program can load the CUDA libraries successfully, and if it can't just fallback